# UITextfield deleteBackward in iOS 5 or lower?

Tags: iphone, ios, subclass

In iOS 6 or > Subclassing UITextField and overriding the `- (void) deleteBackward` method catches the backspace key pressed on number pad keyboard. Any solution for iOS 5 or < ??

In iOS 6, this did it:

```
- (void) deleteBackward  // Overriding in subclass
{
    [super deleteBackward];

    if([self.protocol respondsToSelector:@selector(backspacePressed:)])
        [self.protocol backspacePressed:self];
}
```

Comment: Does anyone still have iOS 5?

Comment: To be on the safe side :S

Answer (score 0):

Using the text field delegates methods we catches the backspace key on number pad keyboard. I did it by following code

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {

    if(string.length == 0) {
      NSLog(@"Backspace key pressed");
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Requirement: Text field should only have one digit. Also clears when editing begins also enabled. So, this will not solve the problem